# Linq value, use Where to Remove items

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to remove items from an `IQueryable` list but the result is only pulling in those items:

```
public IQueryable<Biz.Data.AllItems> items_GetData()
{
    var submissions = Biz.Data.AllItems.LoadNotDeleted().Where(x => 
       // these items need to match to remove the item
       x.itemOne != null && 
       x.itemTwo != null && 
       x.itemThree != null));
    var filter = new Biz.Data.AllItemsFilter();
    return submissions = Biz.Data.Registration.Load(filter).OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);
}
```

Currently, it's only pulling in items that match those instead of removing. I can't use `RemoveAll` because it's not a `List` and I don't want to reformat this because it passes through a filter process after this code. Is there another way to remove items that match these results first before it passes through a filter?

Comment: Not sure I understand. So you want basically the opposite of what you have right now? Then just negate your current condition, e.g. `.Where(x => !(/* your-current-condition-here */))`?

Comment: Yeah I guess that is what I was looking for. Thought I tried this already, but it works now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, simply negate the condition in your predicate.

So if this is your original statement:

```cs
var itemsThatMatch = list.Where(x => /* some condition */);
```

This will give you the opposite:

```cs
var itemsThatDoNotMatch = list.Where(x => !(/* some condition */));
```